# An example ID question

Tags: discussion, identify

I have recently been browsing the newest questions tab and have noticed a constant influx of ID questions. It has been well-established that ID Questions will eventually kill this site and a lot of people dislike them. However, there are good ID questions, some of which even manage to get to the HNQ. One example is [my question here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/72110/48930) which received 17 upvotes and 2 top quality answers.

As I look at these new, poorly-worded questions, I find myself having to comment the same comment over and over again. And I'm sure that @Paulie_D would [agree with me](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/72689/nickelodeon-tv-show#comment117798_72689)

Therefore, I propose that we have a post that can be linked to, that is the perfect example of everything we want in a ID question. In order to decide which question should become this perfect example, you should nominate well-worded questions that you believe are exactly what we are looking for in an ID question.

So that's what this post is about. Please post an answer below, containing a link to a good ID question. Please also provide a short description of why this is a good post. If you think that an example is very good, upvote it. The answer with the most upvotes should then become the question we link to when someone asks a bad ID question.

Comment: Isn't there already one linked from the actual section in the [help center](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson oh yeah. Wonder why I never noticed that.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson i would suggest however that the question also gets linked to in the tag wiki because some people are idiots and don't look in the help section. sure there's nothing making them look at the tag wiki either but it's a bit more visible since they would use the tag